# Unicode support for em-dash

Tags: unicode

I am using XeLaTeX. My goal is to display a Unicode `em dash` in my PDF file. The `\dash` will not compile, below: it says

```
! Undefined control sequence.
```

Here is the minimal (non)-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2014}{\dash}

\begin{document}

hello
\dash
there!

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` is meant to go "the other direction". Why not just `hello — there!`? Furthermore, `inputenc` is ignored for `utf8`-based engines (such as XeLaTeX).

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "the other direction", and I need to be able to use things like \dash in the body of my document for many of the unicode symbols. I want to be able to write in an \aleph and have it print out in the final pdf, for example. There are many Unicode symbols that I want to be able to produce in the final pdf which do not have \dash or \aleph defined for them already.

Comment: Well, `\dash` is undefined at this point.... The first argument is a UTF-8 codepoint; the second argument is what this codepoint maps to.  Try adding: `\def\dash{ASDFASEDR}` to see what Paul means.

Comment: so, please post a working example where I type in the word \dash into my document and expect to see a Unicode character that looks like the em dash in the output pdf.

Comment: OK, so \def\dash{ASDFASEDR} allows me to define the \dash command as ASDFASEDR in the output pdf. How can I print out a Unicode symbol now? Keep in mind, I am not concerned with being able to print dashes. I am concerned with being able to print Unicode symbols.

Comment: Alright, so the point of using XeTeX and XeLaTeX is to type a character directly into a document and have it show up in the output pdf. I am still looking for a way to type in a Unicode code and have the correct Unicode symbol print out in the pdf. What engine should I use? Please give a minimal working example where I can type in the code 2014 and expect to see the em dash output in the pdf. Further, I want to type in the code 2015 and expect to see the next Unicode symbol output in the pdf upon recompiling.

Comment: Mind you, typing `a — b` in the source and compiling with XeLaTeX gets me `a b` so not terribly effective... [That is, if I do not also load `fontspec`. But XeLaTeX alone is not enough. Presumably the default fonts lack the character?]

Comment: Please give an example of some code involving all that: the font change and the \char"2014.

Comment: It is unclear what you want: now(?) you want to type the symbol directly? or do you still want to use things like `\dash`? You haven't told me what font you are using, or what range of unicode you need to type/cover (no font covers it all). Please reformulate your question.

Comment: I am using the default font: see my non-working example here. The range of unicode I am interested in is not the point: please give a minimal, working example for the default font. When I type in \char"2014 into a XeLaTeX-engine compiled file such as the below, it will not produce the em dash. 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\dash{ASDFASEDR}

\begin{document}

hello
\dash
there!
\char"2014

\end{document}

Comment: The range is entirely the point. If you just want to write dashes, use `--` and `---`. I repeat: the font is pretty much all-important here. If the font doesn't matter, then your unicode needs are so minimal that you are making it way more complicated than it needs to be. (And you are still loading `inputenc` and not `fontspec` apparently.)

Comment: Can you give an example using the default font of producing an em dash using the Unicode value 2014? Do not use -- or ---.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are equivalent

```
\documentclass{article}
% XeLaTeX
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{libertine}
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2014}{\dash}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\dash{—}
\newcommand\xdash{---}

\begin{document}

Em-dash: —

Em-dash: ---

Em-dash: \xdash

Em-dash: \dash

Em-dash: \char"2014

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, I hope it's useful. I still feel like a better answer could be given depending on the real goal, but ... well, maybe not. Cheers. (FYI. I wasn't the downvoter.)

Comment: I appreciate your help here - thank you for sticking with it.

Comment: You could of course just use `---` directly in the second argument of `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`.

Comment: I didn't know that \DeclareUnicodeCharacter, is a command of inputenc. I add this comment to others with my same level of knowledge.

Answer (score 8):

Running XeLaTeX in the hope it will print any Unicode character is not successful, as you experienced. Let me explain what went wrong.

The example document

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

will produce exactly the same output with PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX, because only ASCII characters appear. Things will become different if (on an up-to-date distribution) we try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Hello—world!
\end{document}
```

where the character between the words is U+2014 EM DASH and the file is saved as UTF-8. If we process it with PDFLaTeX, we obtain the expected

[image]

but compiling with XeLaTeX we get

[image]

with a couple of warnings in the log file

```
Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

Missing character: There is no — in font cmr10!
```

Why is that? With PDFLaTeX, the input is scanned byte by byte, UTF-8 enters at a later stage. The `utf8` option to `inputenc` tells LaTeX that when the bytes `<E2><80><94>` are found in sequence, they should be transformed into the control sequence `\textemdash` that in turn tells TeX to print the character in position `"7C` (decimal 124) of the current font.

With XeLaTeX, loading `inputenc` is ignored, as stated in the warning message, because XeTeX directly interprets UTF-8, so none of the package's tricks can be of any consequence. This is witnessed by the second warning: upon finding U+2014, XeTeX simply sends it as a character to be printed, but since the current font just has 127 characters, it has none at position decimal 8212.

Of course, the remedy is to load `fontspec` that changes the setup: the default font will not be the legacy Computer Modern, but the OpenType version of Latin Modern that *does* have the character in position `"2014` (decimal 8212). And, indeed,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Hello—world!
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

By the way, also inputting the em-dash in the traditional way `---` would work, because `fontspec` (in its most recent version) automatically applies `Ligatures=TeX`.